# Hashtag lists in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to have lists of hashtags grouped by topic instead of accounts.

Example: A computer list with hashtags `#programming`, `#python`, `#emacs`, etc., then a country list with hashtags `#algeria`, `#maghreb`.

The timelines of each list would display tweets containing any tags in it.

Basically like Twitter lists but with hashtags instead of accounts.

Answer (score 4):

As of writing, you can't create a Twitter list with hashtags. However, I found a [site](https://twitterfall.com) that feeds you tweets based on the hashtags you've provided. I don't think you could group hashtags in this site though. Nevertheless, you can identify each hashtag with its assigned color.

[image]